# CSS selector property overflow value overlay is gone, now what?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, scrollbar, user-experience

The `overflow: overlay` CSS property was a screen reader accessible solution to emulate the immensely popular iOS scrollbars that overlay the scrollable element and are transiently visible on `:hover` or `:focus`. Now that this has been aliased as `overflow: auto` by the [w3c](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6090), the result is an ever-present track, creating a less than desirable squared edge in a lot of scenarios. There are packages out there like [this one](https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/). But these solutions inject many nested `<div>` into the content, which from an screen reader Accessibility perspective is not great, especially for `<table>`. I'm not discussing visual accessibility (4:5:1), nor a requirement to always display a scrollbar on desktop web browser content. I'm referring to a universal technical limitation of how content is represented from a UX perspective.

Here's an example of a custom scrollbar that matches current technical limitations of CSS

[image: Menu with scrollbar]

In the above image, the container has a `border-radius`, but the track creates visual stress.

I created the following SASS mixin:

```
@mixin scroll-bars() {
  overflow: auto;

  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: $space-m;
    width: $space-m;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 24px;
    box-shadow: 4px 0px 0px 4px rgba(105, 113, 127, 0.7) inset;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  // Firefox
  scrollbar-color: rgba(105, 113, 127, 0.7) transparent;
  scrollbar-width: 16px;
}
```

The above does the trick for Safari, Chromium and Opera:

[image]

However, Firefox renders like this:

[image]

If anyone here has been researching a scalable solution to this I would like to read about what your solution may be. As for Firefox, I'm not sure why `transparent` renders as an opaque white track.